# How do I insert page content into the default template in TYPO3?

Tags: templates, content-management-system, typo3, wiki, typoscript

I want to display the same footer content in all pages of my TYPO3 site. It is followed by the Fluid Template concept. I have created 3 templates.

```
   1.default template(main.html)
   2.content template
   3.allpage_content template(which need to show in all pages)
```

Also want that content to be editable in the Rich Text Editor.So I create a page named footer and call the back-end layout(allpage_content.html).

For that  :

```
  lib.footer = COA
  lib.footer {
         10 = CONTENT
         10 {
             table = tt_content
             select.where = colPos = 10
             select.orderBy = sorting
             select.pidInList = 15
            }

      }



page.100 = TEMPLATE
page.100.template = FILE
page.100.template.file = fileadmin/templates/main.html
page.100.workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT_BODY
page.100.marks.content < lib.footer
```

Apart from that  backend layouts  is also connect with real frontend templates

```
 footer_left < styles.content.get
 footer_left.select.where = colPos = 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the below typoscript:

```
lib.footer = COA
lib.footer {
10 = RECORDS
 10{
  tables = tt_content
  source = 15 #footer page id
 }
}
```

OR

```
lib.footer = COA
lib.footer {
 10 = CONTENT
 10 {
 table = tt_content
  select.where = colPos = 0     #column position - 0-normal, 1-left, 2-right, 3-border
  select.orderBy = sorting
  select.pidInList = 15  #footer page id
 }
}
```

Comment: thank you. shall we add the  column position like the:-"select.where = colPos = 0,1,2,3" i mean for more than one column position

Comment: yes.
 colPos = 0 for normal column,  = 1 for left column, = 2 for right  column, = 3 for border

Comment: I mean for more than one column position like this select.where = colPos = 0,1,2,3

Comment: if you need all 3 columns, then just remove "select.where = colPos = 0"

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it.
You can use temp objects for that (they don't persist).
In the example below, only the bodytext (RTE field) is used, nothing else.
Content is rendered through lib.parsefunc_RTE, so Links are rendered.
I chose to pick only one content element (select.max), but that's up to you

```
temp.footer_adr = CONTENT
temp.footer_adr {
   table = tt_content
   select.pidInList = 47
   select.languageField = sys_language_uid
   select.max = 1
   select.begin = 1
   select.selectFields = bodytext
   renderObj=TEXT
   renderObj{
      required=1
      wrap=|
      field=bodytext
      parseFunc = < lib.parseFunc_RTE
  }
}

page.70 = TEMPLATE
page.70 {
    template = FILE
    template.file = fileadmin/templates/main/tmpl/footer.html
    marks {
            FOOTER_ADR < temp.footer_adr
    }
}
```